# Cannot implicitly convert type to List<string>

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, sql-view

Afternoon,

I am getting the following error, and cant work out why... Can some one please take a look and let me know where i am going wrong.

***Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'***

below is what i am trying to use, to get a list back so i can use it with Amazon. I have tried to remove the .ToList() bit but nothing seems to work. I am calling an MS SQL view "GetASINForUpdateLowPrices" which returns a list back of product ASIN's

```
 List<string> prodASINs = dc.GetASINForUpdateLowPrices.ToList();
```

SQL for the view i am using, this may help a little bit more.

```
 SELECT     asin
 FROM         dbo.aboProducts
 WHERE     (asin NOT IN
           (SELECT     aboProducts_1.asin
            FROM       dbo.aboProducts AS aboProducts_1 INNER JOIN
                       dbo.LowestPrices ON aboProducts_1.asin = dbo.LowestPrices.productAsin
            WHERE      (dbo.LowestPrices.priceDate >= DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()))))
```

Comment: You need to initialise the list?

Comment: yeah amazon MWS needs it in this format *sigh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your GetASINForUpdateLowPrices, it wont directly return `List<string>` even if there is only one field in your view. Try the following approach:

```
List<string> prodASINs = dc.GetASINForUpdateLowPrices
                       .Select(item => item.AsinFieldName)
                       .ToList();
```

Visual Studio IntelliSense should suggest you the property name after typing `item.`. If the property is not string try to add .ToString() at the end of the property name.

Edit: After your comment, it seems like you need to use it as `.Select(item => item.asin.ToString())`.

Comment: added, the reason i was using the view was due to the way the SQL was written :)

Comment: cheers, but i can get the list back if i use that. I had similar before, but now i need to only get the ASIN's which have not been updated within the last day :D

Comment: What do you mean by 'getting the list back'?

Comment: its ok, sorted it now, seems you code and Yuck's code worked :)

Answer (score 1):

What data type is a single *ASIN*?

Probably your `GetASINForUpdateLowPrices` is not an `IEnumerable<string>`. Try this to confirm:

```
List<string> prodASINs = dc.GetASINForUpdateLowPrices
                           .Select(e => e.ToString())
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use var.

```
var prodASINs = dc.GetASINForUpdateLowPrices.ToList();
```

Comment: This will work, of course, but if code later is expecting `prodASINs` to be of type `List<string>` it won't work.

Comment: He can figure out what it returns and convert it as necessary.

Comment: cant use a var, as the Amazon code wont accept that. thus why i am using List<string> as thats what they request

Comment: ...which is what my answer is getting at.  He needs to know the type coming from `dc.GetASINForUpdateLowPrices` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `GetASINForUpdateLowPrices.ToList()` creates a List of Strings? My best estimation is that it is a generic list of a different type.

To figure out what is going on -  Change `List<string> prodASINS` to be `Object obj`. Then set a breakpoint to see what List type is actually generated by your ToList() code by checking out the object using the debugger. You can then update your code to move the values into a list of the appropriate type.

You might have to cast the right side of the assignor like this to ultimately get the job done (replacing string with another type if necessary) - `List<string> prodASINs =(List<string>)dc.GetASINForUpdateLowPrices.ToList()`